# android phone restart when run app from eclipse

Tags: android, adb

strange problem here.

My phone reboot every time I run app from eclipse.
App don't install.

EDIT: reboot any time I try to install the app, also if I try 'adb install apppackage.apk'

EDIT2: same thing when I try to install an app from Android Market, fix_permissions not worked

Any ideas?

Comment: SOLVED: restored a Nandroid backup, nothing else worked.

Comment: How you did that? Can you explain?